# Why is that I can visit https webpage containing public files but I can't download them using Python script?

Tags: python, https

What should be my username and password?

```
import requests
import shutil

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2017/QTR1/company.20170111.idx.txt"    

#Note: It's https

r = requests.get(url, auth=('', ''), verify=False,stream=True)

r.raw.decode_content = True

with open("company.20170111.idx.txt", 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to load should be:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2017/QTR1/company.20170103.idx

You're also missing `import requests` and the server-side didn't like the `auth` parameter.

```
import shutil
import requests

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2017/QTR1/company.20170111.idx"

r = requests.get(url, verify=False, stream=True)

r.raw.decode_content = True

with open("company.20170111.idx.txt", 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: import request was there..went above the code i guess.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine. I dont know why :

```
import urllib2
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2017/QTR1/company.20170111.idx"
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
for l in r:
    print l
```